# treeview checked nodes

Tags: c#, treeview

I have used the treeview control in my C# windows application. In that i have a few parent nodes and there child nodes. i have set the ShowCheckboxes properties as ALL.
So if the ckeck box of a parent node or child node is checked how can i get the no. of checked nodes.In the foreach loop what code should i use?
Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Use recursion.  Here's some psuedo code:

```
int GetCount(Node n)
{
  int ret = 0;
  foreach (Node child in n.Nodes)
  {
    ret += GetCount(child);
  }

  return ret + (n.IsChecked() ? 1 : 0);
}
```