# asp.net treeview how to check number of checked child nodes at any level

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a requirement regarding getting finding the number of checked child nodes in a treeview at any particular level. The number of the checked child nodes is to be compared against the total number of nodes per parent. If the number of checked child nodes is less than the total child nodes for that particular parent then this would be considered as limited otherwise its fully checked. I can find the total number of child nodes per parent by using the parent.childnodes.count property. I am failing to find a way of getting this number.

REgards,

imdondo

Comment: possible duplicates - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605398/treeview-checked-nodes?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Recursive lambda function `FlattenTree` should do the trick.

```
Func<TreeNodeCollection, IEnumerable<TreeNode>> FlattenTree = null;
FlattenTree = coll => coll.Cast<TreeNode>()
                          .Concat(coll.Cast<TreeNode>()
                                      .SelectMany(x => FlattenTree(x.ChildNodes))
                           );

var nodesCount = FlattenTree(treeView.Nodes).Count();
var checkedNodesCount = FlattenTree(treeView.Nodes).Count(x=>x.Checked);
```

Other Linq2Object functions are also possible

```
var checkedLeafNodes = FlattenTree(treeView.Nodes)
                       .Where(x => x.ChildNodes.Count == 0 && x.Checked==true)
                       .ToList();
```